# How can I run asp.net project Locally IIS 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have a asp.net project that i deploy onto an environment using TFS-2017 Release Managment We have problems that when we deploy the website users have old (cached) images/content I want to configure IIS 7 so that i can Test few solutions locally, the website opens on localhost:89 but when i click a button it re-directs me to a live website, I tried configuring the Hosts file with

```
127.0.0.1 example.com
127.0.0.1 www.example.com
```

But this does not work, my web.config file has a lot of appSettings that contain
urls that's what causing me to redirect (I Think).

**QUESTION:** How can I configure IIS so it only uses the Localhost:89 and when I click a button it will redirect me instead of www.example.com to 127.0.0.1:89?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How can I configure IIS so it only uses the Localhost:89 and when I click a button it will redirect me instead of www.example.com to 127.0.0.1:89?

> You cannot configure IIS  for this

IIS does not redirect on it's own it is the application which is doing it.If your application has code written to redirect to another page,from IIS side you cannot do anything.The flow will be like this

1. User Clicks on a button
2. On the asp.net side,application code does some processing(may be checks the incoming URL and if it does not match something) and redirct to www.example.com.This sends a response 302 status(or any 301 or 307) with Location header pointing to www.example.com
3. Your browser sees the 302 status and redirects the user to www.example.com

Since redirection is a response message send by application and the actual redirection is done by the browser ,from IIs side you cannot do much.

As you were doing you can tell the browser that www.example.com is localhost(by editing hosts(C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) file.But that has nothing to do with IIS.

You have to check with application developers to see why it is redirecting and have conditional redirects based on settings.

The Hosts file configuration looks fine

```
127.0.0.1 example.com
127.0.0.1 www.example.com
```

But you may already know what it only works in the same machine.So if you ping www.example com from command line,you should get the output as follows

```
D:\>ping www.example.com

Pinging www.example.com [127.0.0.1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

One your ping works fine,you have to close the browser completely and reopen it(if chrome,close all instances of chrome).Then access www.example.com from your browser and it should go to localhost.

Comment: Great Answer!, So how could edit the hosts file to make it work my example above does not work. I couldn't find much more about this.

Comment: added more details to the answer.let me know if you need something else

Comment: I just noticed that its `https:/ /www.example.com` (without the space) does that make a diffrence? I am getting the same output in command prompt as you but when i try to access it it does not work.

Comment: what is the error you are receiving when you access https://www.example.com . To get this working,you also should have proper binding in IIS(if not already there) . D

Comment: I dont get any errors the webpage just opens normally. Binding "Type:http"       IP address: All Unassigned Port 89." -- Thats what i have in IIS

Comment: if the redirection is done to https:/ /www.example.com and that is pointing to localhost,then you should have a binding for https and All Unassigned(or 127.0.0.1) port and port as 443.This also needs a certificate which you can use selfsigned certificate

Comment: I did That, It does not work, i dont want what the issue is i tried every tutorial   that i seen but nothings seems to work